# Noda Time Instant to CET

Tags: c#, .net-core, nodatime

I'm using the Noda Time libarary (v 2.0.3) for date time handling in a .net core project. However; I'm having some issues converting an instant to a CET date-time.

I'm fairly new to Noda Time, possibly using it wrong (is not CET tz-db entry referring to CET at all)?

Example code

```
// get current system instant
var systemInstant = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();

// get oslo zoneddatetime from instant
var osloDateTime = systemInstant.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Oslo"]);
// get CET(?) zoneddatetime from instant
var cetDateTime = systemInstant.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["CET"]);

// output
Debug.WriteLine(osloDateTime.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine(cetDateTime.ToString());
```

The output from the example code above gives me:

```
2017-06-16T22:28:16 Europe/Oslo (+02)
2017-06-16T22:28:16 CET (+02)
```

Acutally I was expecting the CET zoned time to be 21:28:16 (UTC+1) and not 22:28:16 (UTC+2). UTC+1 is also what the [Time and date website](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet) displaying.

Comment: BTW - If you want a time zone that is UTC+1 all year round, you can use `Etc/GMT-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Zone` line of the `europe` file in the IANA time zone database contains this single line for the `CET` zone ID:

```
Zone    CET     1:00    C-Eur   CE%sT
```

Then the end recurrence of the `C-Eur` rule is this pair of lines:

```
Rule    C-Eur   1981    max -   Mar lastSun  2:00s  1:00    S
Rule    C-Eur   1996    max -   Oct lastSun  2:00s  0   -
```

So it goes into UTC+2 at 2am on the last Sunday of March each year, and back to UTC+1 at 2am on the last Sunday of October each year.

Note that the "abbreviation" in the CET time zone will vary between "CET" and "CEST" - and that may be what's misleading you. But Noda Time *is* following the definition of the *ID* "CET" as per the IANA database.

This is just another reason to avoid using the abbreviations, and instead to use full zone IDs such as Europe/Oslo which are unambiguous. I would suggest avoid trying to use the concept of "a CET date-time" entirely.

Comment: Thanks, It all makes so much more sense now. As you suggested, I think it is the CET/CEST difference that confused me.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the result of DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["CET"], it has a minimum offset of +1 and a maximum offset of +2, so I think it is refering to the actual central European timezone (including the Central European Summer Time [CEST]).

As the date you selected falls into the summer time range, it is UTC+2.

If you try the following you get UTC+1 for CET:

```
Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(new DateTime(2017, 01, 01, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["CET"]
```